# Construct dynamic timer with lua

Tags: timer, lua

I have created a timer called "timer", but I'm trying to create a function that will arm or disarm timer which is specified in it parameters

```
timer = sys.timer.create()
```

`function MainTimer(timerName, action, time)
  if action == "arm" then
    timerName:arm(time)
  else 
    timerName:disarm()
  end
end`

```
MainTimer("timer", "arm", 30)
```

but I'm getting an error from lua saying lua:272: attempt to call method 'arm' (a nil value)

where you think I did a mistake. 
Thank you

Comment: It seems that neither timer object nor class table doesn't have `arm` field initialized.

Comment: if i replace the timerName by timer it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra quotes :-)

```
MainTimer(timer, "arm", 30)
```